# Cannot find module 'next' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, yarnpkg, tsconfig

Getting `Cannot find module '' or its corresponding type declarations.` when importing in Next.js project.

This happens on every single import. [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIW1b.png)

Yarn version : 3.1.0-rc.2
Next version: 11.1.2

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    // "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
}
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, did you run `yarn`?

Comment: yes, but just in case can you show how I'm supposed to run it, lol

Comment: Really just in the directory where your package.json is, run `yarn` in your terminal / commandline. The only cause for the messages you describe is the packages either not being installed *or* VSCode not having indexed the node_modules directory.

Comment: Well, the packages are installed by `yarn install`, yet i don't have node_module folder. Only .yarn and yarn.lock

Comment: Hmmm, you mentioned that you are using Yarn 3, which uses PnP by default so it won't generate a node_modules folder. Have you looked at the editor support section of their [migration guide](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#editor-support)? Maybe that helps get VSCode up to speed indexing the installed dependencies

Comment: One solution could be that instead of importing from `next/app`, you can import from `next/app.js`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you're using yarn 3 and VSCode, then you need to follow these steps to set up your editor:

- Run `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`
- Open any `TypeScript` file
- Press `ctrl+shift+p`
- Choose "Select TypeScript Version"
- Pick "Use Workspace Version"

[Read here](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks#editor-setup) for other editors

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Comment: I'm using Neovim, not VS Code, but the link to [Yarn's documentation on editor SDKs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks#neovim-native-lsp) was what I needed.

Comment: What if I told you it still throws the error...

Comment: You need to install this extension first but then this worked for me, thanks  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=arcanis.vscode-zipfs

Answer (score 79):

**Maybe just restarting the TS server can work.**

**VsCode - Windows**

type: `ctrl + shift + p`

choose: `> TypeScript: Restart TS server`

**VsCode - Macbook:**

type: `⇧ + ⌘ + P or F1`

choose: `> TypeScript: Restart TS server`

Comment: This is the way

Comment: It's gone for 2 seconds and again it came back.. 

Comment: This solution is a life saver

Comment: It saved for my time

Answer (score 17):

I tried solution suggested by Cuong Vu and many others and it didn't work. For me what worked was the following solution:

In Yarn 2/3, support for modules in the node_modules folder is removed because of PnP. Follow the steps below to resolve the issue.

1. Create a `.yarnrc.yml` file in the project root,
2. Insert in the file `nodeLinker: node-modules`.
3. Run the command `yarn` in the terminal to recreate the node_modules folder.

Following all 3 steps the problem will be solved.

Comment: Ass saver! Though it is generating the node_modules folder, is that the wanted outcome?

Comment: @URogel Yarn PNP (Plug'n'Play) is amazing, it doesn't use the node_modules folder, it has quick dependency installation and you use much less disk space.

But it is necessary to ensure that ALL project dependencies have PnP support.

Although I have already read somewhere that next.js has standard support for PnP, I realize that it doesn't always work. ```nodeLinker: node-modules``` ensures that the node_module folder is recreated and yarn 2/3 behaves like yarn 1 or npm.

Comment: I made it work by using the suggested solution by Cuong Vu _while_ using Yarn PnP

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to provide more context and additional notes for others who might appreciate them.

0. Just reread @Vagnerlandio Nunes's answer, and it was spot on. Problem solved!
1. Recap/Solution #2: I was simply bootstrapping a new project using `npx create-next-app`, following the Next.js' [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started) with `npx create-next-app@latest --typescript` (using `yarn`) or ran `yarn create next-app --typescript`. I got errors relating to `ts(2307): Cannot find module 'next/app' or its corresponding type declarations.`
2. With @warfield's answer, I noticed I did not have a `node_modules` folder for some reason, and it was not created even after I ran `yarn`. I had to run `npm i` to create the `node_modules` folder, even though I planned to use `yarn`.

This is the log I got when I ran `yarn`.

```
% yarn
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0000: │ ESM support for PnP uses the experimental loader API and is therefore experimental
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 0s 244ms
```

This is the log I got when I ran `npm i`.

```
% npm i  

added 235 packages, and audited 236 packages in 10s

78 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Now the problem is solved, and the error messages have gone away!

3. But out of curiosity, I ran `yarn` again, and this is the resulting output.

```
% yarn
➤ YN0070: Migrating from Yarn 1; automatically enabling the compatibility node-modules linker 

➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 3s 864ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0013: │ word-wrap@npm:1.2.3 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ wrappy@npm:1.0.2 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yallist@npm:4.0.0 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yocto-queue@npm:0.1.0 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0019: │ ms-npm-2.1.3-81ff3cfac1-aa92de6080.zip appears to be unused - removing
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 303ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0007: │ core-js-pure@npm:3.25.5 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 4s 288ms
➤ YN0000: Done in 8s 486ms
```

4. In addition, if you're like me, you tried to modify your `tsconfig.json` file from

```
...
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
...
```

to

```
...
"include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "pages/**/*",
    "src/**/*",
],
...
```

because you thought it was going to help based on this GitHub [comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19891). You would now be seeing a new error message `ts(2686): 'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.`. This is not necessary if you simply did the above step. So I just changed it back.

5. Changing your `tsconfig.json`'s `"compilerOptions": { ... }` from `"jsx": "preserve"` to `"jsx": "react-jsx"` is also not necessary ([reference to another attempted solution](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-typescript-cannot-find-name#:%7E:text=To%20solve%20the%20%22Cannot%20find,types%20packages%20for%20your%20application.)).

6. At any point if you want to make sure that the changes you've made (in regards to tsconfig) has gone into effect, try **command + shift + p** and enter `> TypeScript: Restart TS server`, and you should see some refreshing going on.

Answer (score 4):

Before attempting other solutions:

1. Double check you have a `node_modules` folder
2. If not, run `yarn` (or `npm i`) to (re)install the modules

Accidentally deleting the node_modules folder is the simplest explanation for the `TS2307 Cannot find module ''` error.

It's also supported by OP comments

> "i don't have node_module folder. Only .yarn and yarn.lock"

h/t @geisterfurz007's comments.

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my tsconfig.json file
I can see you have it already, but it was not part of my solution

```
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the above answers I tried configuring my editor as per https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks

I restarted and still had the problem

In the end I have downgraded yarn which resolves my issue

`yarn set version classic && yarn install`

Now I have node_modules and vscode is happy

I also prefer to have the source code available to browse - [apparently vscode should be able to access the source code](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/1183) but this was also not working for me (and I like having the raw files to search)

Answer (score 0):

In my case below step `worked(MacOs & VSCode)`

Step 1. `command + shift + p` and

Step 2. Search > `TypeScript: Restart TS server` and press **enter**

Answer (score 0):

For my solution, simply a user error. I had made new aliases, but they require the star on the key.

So this:

```
"paths": {
      ...,
      "@lib/": ["./app/lib/*"],
    },
```

Becomes this:

```
"paths": {
  ...,
  "@lib/*": ["./app/lib/*"],
},
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the module I was trying to use was in `node_modules/`.

For example - `/next/font/google`

The fix was to add the relative path to paths in **tsconfig.json**

```
    "paths": {
        "@/*": ["./*"],
        "/*": ["./node_modules/*"]
    }
```