# NextJs setup in vscode using Yarn

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js, yarnpkg

I ran `yarn create next-app --typescript` to create a TypeScript Next app using Yarn. The app runs fine using `yarn run dev`; however, vscode does not read any of the yarn packages added.
[image: editor view]
I've tried following the instructions on the official [Yarn's Editor SDKs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks#caveat) article by running:

```bash
yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode
```

[image: execution logs]
then selecting the TypeScript Version.

Comment: Did you try using `import Head from 'next/head'`?

Comment: @MaartenDev Yes. The project runs fine but still vscode doesn't find any of the packages (Autocomplete, Intellisense, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue but i found solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/73001522/2991626

just create `.yarnrc.yml` and add 1 line content `nodeLinker: node-modules` then just type command `yarn` and vscode will works with yarn

Comment: This just uses `node_modules` instead, it doesn't use Yarn's own PnP. This is just a backup in case it doesn't work, it's not a real solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same error in 2024 there is question where I found the solution - [How to configure VSCode to run Yarn 2 (with PnP) powered TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65328123/how-to-configure-vscode-to-run-yarn-2-with-pnp-powered-typescript). I had the same issue, and installation of additional dev dependencies (`typescript`, `prettier` and `eslint`) before command `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode` solved the issue.